# How to isolate duplicates based on partial match in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, partial-matches

I have a pandas data frame, which looks like the following:

```
email                   col2  col3
email@example.com       John  Doe
xxxemail@example.com    John  Doe
xxemail@example.com     John  Doe
xxxxxemail@example.com  John  Doe
xxxemail@example2.com   Jane  Doe
```

I want to go through each email address starting with at least two 'x's and check whether the same email address exists without those 'x's.

Required result:

```
email                   col2  col3  exists_in_valid_form
email@example.com       John  Doe   False
xxxemail@example.com    John  Doe   True
xxemail@example.com     John  Doe   True
xxxxxemail@example.com  John  Doe   True
xxxemail@example2.com   Jane  Doe   False
```

I was able to get a sub-data frame containing all of those rows with the emails starting with 'xx' using `df[df['email'].str.contains("xx")]`, and was also able to get the email addresses without the 'x's using `str.lstrip('x')`, but neither does not seem to help me get whether this email appears somewhere else without those x's or not.

Comment: I think using str.lstrip('x') will also strip out the x in the word example in the email. I suppose it would still work in this case, as it would remove from everything, but may cause issues in actual data

Comment: @EmiOB I verified it does not remove anything once the next character is not an 'x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated()` to get whether a value is existing in other row.

```
df['exists_in_valid_form'] = df.email.str.lstrip('x').duplicated(keep=False) & df.email.str.startswith('xx')
```

I added `df.email.str.startswith('xx')` to make sure it should start with at least 2 "x" and return False for "xemail@example.com".

Comment: I think you should add `keep=False` to `duplicated` because otherwise is fails if the valid form is not the first occurence of the duplicates (for example if you swap the first two rows).